# Google API/get directory contacts

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I need get list of contacts/phones from google buisness directory listing.

I have tried Google Contacts api, it work ok for all contacts under "My Contacts", but not allow show "Directory" contacts.

What i have use/how to access thoose contacts(company ones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add users to the Global Address List (GAL), use the [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/). It's similar to the regular Contacts API but is only accessible to admins and has a special URL.

Comment: this one is correct answer. Unfortanly it require domain administration user privileges, which greatly decrease posible use case

Comment: For end user read access to the gal see my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16281326/1503886

Comment: Doesn't metter. I have set via admin user with OAuth 2 and session store. Work ok.

Answer (score 2):

Note that to get all users on an account is now possible by using the [Uses:list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) endpoint.

By default, this information is only available to administrators, but a teammate just found that you can set the `viewType` parameter to `domain_public` which allows anyone within the org to get a list of everyone on the domain.

We spent hours looking into this before we saw the option, so I thought I'd leave a note here for anyone else looking for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The Directory contacts are the users of the Google Apps account. You can access them using the Directory API : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Comment: I have tried that, thoose api always return "403 Not Authorized to access this resource/api". Even when Admin SDK API enabled.

Comment: You can try the Google APIs Explorer [https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.users.list] and look at Google API in Java [https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/]

Comment: yes, i know about explorer. give same result. Looks like need be domain admin to read directory. Will test with more privileges.