# Domain Shared Contacts API with Google Apps

Tags: google-apps, google-contacts-api, google-data-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm using Contacts API to get the list of all the contacts in the domain to give the suggestions to the user.

I'm using "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/example.com/full" as URL.
Got the errot saying "Only administrators can request entries belonging to example".

How to get the list of Domain contacts using API ?.
I'm able to access the contacts from browser using this url "https://www.google.com/contacts/?hl=en&tab=wC#contacts/group/27/Directory".

please help......!!!

EDIT 1(With Jay reference):
My code is:

`service.setHeader("GData-Version", "1.0");
ContactFeed  contactEntry= service.getFeed(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/gal/example.com/full?alt=json&q=mail@example.com"), ContactFeed.class);`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281326/how-to-get-google-profile-info-including-custom-fields-from-an-apps-domain-user

Comment: i tried it, Got com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
Version 3.0 is not supported.

Comment: tried setting service.setHeader("GData-Version", "1.0"); Didn't work

Comment: It is working fine from OAuth playground. Thanks..!!

Comment: How to limit the number of results ..?

Comment: max-results=1 worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

`$.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/gal/domain.com/full",
                    data: { 
                        alt: "json",
                        q:query, 
                        access_token:access_token,
                        'max-results':10
                        },
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                    }
                });`

scope:`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`