# Google Global Address List for Domain limited to 250 results

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to query Google Global Address List for a specific domain, being led by this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281326/how-to-get-google-profile-info-including-custom-fields-from-an-apps-domain-user) (Specifically the answer by Jay Lee).

It's all well and good and works perfectly in Google's OAuth Playground, however it seems to be limited to 250 users. Given that this feature seems completely undocumented, and that I can't tell by looking at their github repo (specifically [this file](https://github.com/google/gfw-deployments/blob/master/apps/shell/gal/gal_feed.sh)), does anyone know how to query for the next 250 users or how to set the number of results?

Thank you!